# How to log in as a user in user_controller_spec?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, authentication, specifications

A person is not allowed to look at the users page unless they are an admin. Hence users cannot leave the home page if they aren't logged in. In the user_controller_spec we have several tests on editing personal info or passwords. But the tests will never pass because the user we created in the spec class is not logged in. Is there a way to log in the user in the user_controller_spec?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Devise for authentication , it provides a helper method : `sign_in`

So you can do something like this :

```
it "should do something" do
  sign_in(user) # user is an object of your User model
  #Continue testing
end
```

See [this documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers) for more information.

Comment: I am using sessions. I have no idea how to use Devise. Can I do it without it?

Comment: You can set your session inside a spec using `session[:key]` . You can write your own helper method `sign_in(user)` , which can set the session for the user to be signed in. You can use this in your specs when you want a user to log in .